# Reference order while using utf8 and biber

Tags: unicode, biber

I have a problem with ordering of the references, while using `utf8` with biber. I need utf8, because some surnames in Slovenian use Š, Č and Ž (I know I could use `\v{}` syntax, but biber complains during execution).

The problem is that among all I have three articles whose respective first authors are Zachry, Žnider and Zupavec (the surnames are made-up). I am using the apa style for formatting and biber for bibliography generation. When I compile my source files with `pdflatex`, `biber` and 2x`pdflatex` I get a strange result:

- Zachry
- Žnider
- Zupavec

Here, Zachry comes before Žnider and Zupavec (OK)! But Žnider comes before Zupavec (not OK)!!!

The expected result would be:

- Zachry
- Zupavec
- Žnider

Anyway, from these results I would assume that `biber` handles characters `Z` and `Ž` in the same way (maybe mapping them both to ascii `Z`), and the bibliography is ordered by their second character of the surname - `a`, `n` and `u` respectively.

Is there a workaround for this problem. I suspect this is a bug in `biber`.

I also include a MWE:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}

First Citation: \parencite{Znider}

Second Citation: \parencite{Zupavec}

Third Citation: \parencite{Zach}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

ref.bib

```
@ARTICLE{Zach,
   author = {Zachry, John},
   title = {Foo},
   journal = {Bar},
   volume = {1},
   number = {2},
   pages = {123-345},
   year = {1999},
}

@ARTICLE{Znider,
  author = {Žnider, Jože},
  title = {Bar},
  journal = {Foo},
  volume = {12},
  number = {123},
  pages = {11-12},
  year = {1999},
}

@ARTICLE{Zupavec,
  author = {Zupavec, Miha},
  title = {FooBar},
  journal = {BarBar},
  volume = {100},
  pages = {132-154},
  number = {2},
  year = {1999},
}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: I think there is a field "sortname" or similar, which should help you, check the manual

Comment: The sorting should be done according to the rules of the main document's language, in this case American English. What if you have a Czech author whose name starts with “Ch” that, according to Czech rules, goes after “H” in collating order? It may disturb your Slovene soul, but it's what makes people find things more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the sorting manually with the field `sortname`:

```
@ARTICLE{Znider,
  author = {Žnider, Jože},
  title = {Bar},
  journal = {Foo},
  volume = {12},
  number = {123},
  pages = {11-12},
  year = {1999},
  sortname = {Zznider, Jože}
}
```

Comment: Cool. However I think this should anyway be fixed in biber, given they are advertising full utf8 support. :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't find the sorting wrong. But sorting depends on the language and in biblatex you can change the locale. I have no idea which locale sorts the Ž as you want it, but e.g this here would sort Ž before Z:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,bibencoding=utf8,sortlocale=sl-SI]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}

First Citation: \parencite{Znider}

Second Citation: \parencite{Zupavec}

Third Citation: \parencite{Zach}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Output with Texlive 2014

[image]

## Output with Texlive 2015

[image]

As the output differs between the version I will make a bug report at the biber site.

Comment: Ž should go *after* Z.

Comment: @egreg: If you tell me in which locale I will change the example. I was already happy to find one where it doesn't count simply as Z ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This seems a more native way to deal with the issue. However in Slovenian Ž comes after Z (as stated by @egreg).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, in my experiment the order is different than yours.

Comment: @egreg I get a different sorting with texlive 2014 than with texlive 2015 (the image shows tl2015). So either there is bug in biber which should be reported, or the sorting rules has changed ...

Comment: I get the image that I added replacing yours, with TeX Live 2015.

Comment: @egreg there is a biber update waiting. I will recheck after installation.

Comment: @egreg: I still get the "wrong" sorting, so I made a bug report.

Comment: I took a quick look at the code, and it seems that language locale is used in Perl sorting functions (called by biber). Which means, that maybe there is a bug in Perl implementation.

Comment: Hmm, I get the correct sort order with TL15 with both lualatex and pdflatex (not the sort order in your image). This is on OSX however. Is anyone else not using windows and can check?

Comment: Here, with Ubuntu and TeXLive 2015, I get the correct order (the same as your image from TeXLive 2014)...

Comment: @PLK: I checked also with my win 8.1 laptop and there I get the wrong sorting too (only with TL15, with TL14 everything is fine -- one the same PC!).

Comment: @PLK: And with a  `Biber 4.0 (beta)` (which I installed on May, 1) the sorting is fine again.

Comment: This is very mysterious. I think we need some more tests. Can you send me a --trace output of your TL 2015 run?

Comment: @PLK: Is on the way ...